# Native javascript - merge two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to merge two array like :

```
arr1 = [
    ['01/09',1],
    ['02/09',2],
    ['03/09',3],
    ['04/09',4]
];

arr2 = [
    ['01/09',13],
    ['03/09',14],
    ['04/09',15],
    ['05/09',16]
];
```

**I want an output like this :**

```
res = [
    ['01/09',1,13],
    ['02/09',2,0],
    ['03/09',3,14],
    ['04/09',4,15],
    ['05/09',0,16]
]
```

I really want some solutions! Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate. The question you pointed merges two arrays of simple values in a single one, here the values themselves are merged together: `['01/09', 1]` and `['01/09', 13]` gives `['01/09', 1, 13]`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide necessary details.

Comment: In fact, concat doesn't detect duplicate, it just add the second array to the first array.

Comment: I've added my solution ( using concat + map )

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combined approach to build the empty array with the parameters adn iterate and build a hash table for the matched items. Then apply the value.

```js
function merge(arrays) {
    var hash = Object.create(null),
        merged = [];

    arrays.forEach(function (a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (b) {
            if (!hash[b[0]]) {
                hash[b[0]] = Array.apply(null, { length: arrays.length + 1 }).map(function () { return 0 });
                hash[b[0]][0] = b[0];
                merged.push(hash[b[0]]);
            }
            hash[b[0]][i + 1] = b[1];
        });
    });
    return merged;
}

var arr1 = [['01/09', 1], ['02/09', 2], ['03/09', 3], ['04/09', 4]],
    arr2 = [['01/09', 13], ['03/09', 14], ['04/09', 15], ['05/09', 16]];

console.log(merge([arr1, arr2]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ok! i will test it and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.find` to search in array and then use `Array.concat` to merge them.

#### Array.find + array.concat

```js
var arr1 = [
  ['01/09', 1],
  ['02/09', 2],
  ['03/09', 3],
  ['04/09', 4]
];

var arr2 = [
  ['01/09', 13],
  ['03/09', 14],
  ['04/09', 15],
  ['05/09', 16]
];

var result = arr1.map(function(a1) {
  var _tmp = arr2.find(x => x[0] === a1[0]) || [];
  return a1.concat(_tmp.splice(1));
});

console.log(result)
```

Though, I would suggest you to use following structure as it would be more scalable.

#### Map object

```js
var arr1 = [
  ['01/09', 1],
  ['02/09', 2],
  ['03/09', 3],
  ['04/09', 4]
];

var arr2 = [
  ['01/09', 13],
  ['03/09', 14],
  ['04/09', 15],
  ['05/09', 16]
];
var result = {};
arr1.forEach(function(item) {
  result[item[0]] = item.slice(1) || [];
});

arr2.forEach(function(item) {
  result[item[0]] = result[item[0]] || [];
  result[item[0]] = result[item[0]].concat(item.slice(1))
});

console.log(result)
```

Few pointers,

- `array.concat` will return merged string but will not update the variable. So don't forget to assign it.
- `array.find` has compatibility issues. Do check them before using it. You can also use `array.filter` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr1 = [
  ['01/09', 1],
  ['02/09', 2],
  ['03/09', 3],
  ['04/09', 4]
];

var arr2 = [
  ['01/09', 13],
  ['03/09', 14],
  ['04/09', 15],
  ['05/09', 16]
];

var arr3 = [
  ['01/09', 130],
  ['03/09', 140],
  ['04/09', 150],
  ['05/09', 160]
];


function mergeArrays() {
  var resultObj = {},
    resultArray = [];
  var array = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  array.map(function(item) {
    var key = item[0];
    if (!this[key]) {
      this[key] = [];
      this[key].push(key);
    }
    this[key].push(item[1]);
  }, resultObj);

  for (var key in resultObj) {
    resultArray.push(resultObj[key]);

  }
  return resultArray;
}
console.log(mergeArrays(arr1, arr2, arr3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `reduce()` and `forEach()`

```js
var arr1 = [
  ['01/09', 1],
  ['02/09', 2],
  ['03/09', 3],
  ['04/09', 4]
];
var arr2 = [
  ['01/09', 13],
  ['03/09', 14],
  ['04/09', 15],
  ['05/09', 16]
];

var obj = {}
var result = arr1.reduce(function(r, e) {

  arr2.forEach(function(el, i) {
    if (!obj[e[0]]) {
      obj[e[0]] = [e[0], 0, 0];
      r.push(obj[e[0]]);
    }

    obj[e[0]][1] = e[1];
    if (el[0] == e[0]) {
      obj[e[0]][2] = el[1];
    } else {
      if (!obj[el[0]]) {
        obj[el[0]] = [el[0], 0, el[1]];
        r.push(obj[el[0]]);
      }
    }
  })

  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```